# Heterogenous data between classes in object detector

Tags: neural-network, object-detection

I have created a synthetic dataset for object detection with about a dozen classes by placing models of the classes in front of random images (from the [MIT Place2](http://places2.csail.mit.edu/download.html) dataset) in Blender. This is working fantastically on those classes, because they're simple shapes that are quite easy to model.

However, I want to train a new model with all of these classes, plus one additional class -- people. I can't generate the people annotations the same way; besides, there are many datasets already out there which contain people as a class. Specifically, I am looking at the [Visidrone dataset](http://aiskyeye.com/). I can take one of those and extract the person annotations from it. However, the "background" behind the object will be different, as they are taken from a real instead of a synthetic context.

I'm wondering: if I "meld" the two datasets together, the one containing the many blender-created classes, and the other containing the real people, will the one class cross-contaminate the other, in either direction? I'm assuming that the number of training examples is similar between classes.

The model I am training is an EfficientDet.

Comment: Are the 2 datasets comparable? The 2 datasets you've mentionned seem to have different angles of view for most of them, which could generate bias in the learning process. My suggestion is to take just one dataset to learn both classes, including learning one from scratch.